# (Gatbsy-React) Dynamic Path: how persist pages dynamically created with API to be crawled by Google Bot, and visited directly by users

Tags: reactjs, web-crawler, gatsby, react-router-v4, dynamic-pages

I have this big issue.
I have developed a Gatsby website for the car parts market.
The users can select car model and part type and receive a page with the parts for their specific car.

I have used React Route to create dynamically the new path and an API that recall the data:
https:/mysiteAPI.com/{car.id}/{part.id}

The paths that will be created are something like that: https:/mysite.com/comparison/{car.name}-{part.name}

The big issue that I have is that this path will be created only when i click on

Using this approach I can not generate the pages when I build the website, but the pages will be generated only when users click.

Actually I need that pages will be readable from search engine crawlers for SEO reasons.

I tried to create each page inserting in Gatsby Node a CreatePage, but the system crashed, due the huge amount of pages (over 5 million).

I don’t know how to generate pages that can be readable by crowler and persist. I hope that someone of you can help me to improve my site.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [createPages](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#createPages) API, available in the [gatsby-node](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node) file of your project. If you would like to create static HTML files in the build process for each item you need to first fetch them somehow. With the data in your possession you could iterate over it and call `createPage` for each page you want to create.